# Difference between calling a script in the onload event or placing code at end of html

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-parsing

I was reading the google maps api documentation and stumbled across a paragraph that explains the Asynchronously Loading the API. The api documentation can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)

As an example it showed a script that looks like this:

```
function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=TRUE_OR_FALSE&callback=initialize";
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;
```

What is the difference between this piece of code and just simply adding the script call all the way to the end of the html markup? Like this:

```
        <!-- rest of the markup -->

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=TRUE_OR_FALSE&callback=initialize"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually want your JS scripts to run after the DOM is loaded and this event doesn't necessarily occur when your html is read/parsed.  I.E.  There exists some time between reading the HTML and building the DOM that your JS needs to traverse.